Why are safety kicks further back than regular kickoffs?
Under the current version of the NFL's kickoff rules, standard kickoffs are kicked from the A35 yard line, but safety kicks are set further back to the A20 yard line. With the exception of things like the landing zones and restraining lines, my understanding is that this is substantially similar to the previous iterations on the kickoff rules.
Given this has been the standard for some time now, is there a specific reason why the rules are setup to further penalize a team that just had a safety scored on them? It seems that if Team B scores a safety on Team A, not only are they awarded 2 points and possession, but they're further awarded a chance at much better starting field position on the kickoff.
Is this just because safeties are so difficult to achieve and 2 points isn't considered sufficient by itself? Or is there another reason to grant Team B better field position?

Nij addressed issues of "fairness". However, I think history is a more likely explanation of why a kick after safety is different from a kick after a touchdown or field goal.
Dig into the history of American Football and you'll find that what is now called a safety was essentially the same as a touchback. (Football Archaeology was the first web site I found documenting this, although I remember reading about it in a forgotten book decades ago.) In fact, a team could start a play from scrimmage outside its own endzone, run backwards into its own endzone, take a knee, and then start with a new set of downs at their 25 yard line. They were said to be doing this "for safety". Obviously such a rule could be - and was - abused. Thus the rule was changed so that the team with the ball couldn't do this intentionally, and doing so would result in a kick from the 25. Given the linkage between the safety and the touchback, it would make sense that moving the starting point after a touchback to the 20 yard line would also move the kicking point after a safety.

Your question of fairness is flipped over. Instead, ask: why should the attacking team be penalised simply because they have done well?
The fact that a safety is only two points, while a touchdown is six (plus the conversion for more), should support the restart of play being less advantageous to the defending team, because the attacking team has done the same amount of work but not obtained the same reward earned by it.
Compare with similar sports like rugby union or rugby league. If the ball is made dead in-goal, the restart is more advantageous to the attacking team if it occurred due to poor play by the defending team (who should not escape danger more eaisly by playing worse), but more balanced if it occurred due to poor play by the attacking team (who had an opportunity and wasted it)
